# How to search external storage for a specific folder name in Android

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I searched for this specific instant all over stack overflow and internet. But cannot get the result. Hence i am forced to ask this community.

I want to list all the folders and sub folders in external storage, and find a specific folder by its name i.e, "dtbackup". Yes i know i can list the folders with this code.

```
  public void listallfolders() {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File f = new File(path);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (File inFile : files) {
            if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
                // is directory
                   try {
               Log.d("search_opr", inFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   }
            }
        }
```

This returns the folder path but only top level folders, sub folders and deep folders are not listed. i have tried numerous method but i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: so, solution is simple, once you know that `isDirectory()` is true then it means it is a folder and you need to call the recursive function to search in the branch too. 

You are looking a traversing a tree solution. Depth First or Breadth-First Search.

Comment: any hints? for that bro??

Comment: What hint ? You are doing okay with the above code, you just have to call it recursively.

Comment: yes i figured out and called the function recursively but it only returns the name if it has any file. empty folder is not returning.